# Get single element from Firebase Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

I am trying to receive a single element from within my firebase database and place said element into a table. I have completed my task once but it didn't save correctly and I have spent an eternity trying to refigure the js

I aim to get the userName from a specific team ID for example 1009254444.

The database is structured data/xbox/3787955/teams/109254444 userName value is within this element "?"

https://cfm-stats.firebaseio.com/data.json

The code I have so far is

**HTML**

```
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-standings sortable">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Coach</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='userName'></tbody>
    </table>
  </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #aa010b;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**js**

```
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "****",
          authDomain: "****",
          databaseURL: "****",
          projectId: "cfm-stats",
          storageBucket: "****",
          messagingSenderId: "****",
          appId: "****",
          measurementId: "****"


}

    ;
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('data/xbox/3787955/teams');
    var ref = rootRef.child('1009254444');
    ref.on('value', function(snap) {
        document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "";
        snap.forEach(function(child) {
          var childData = child.val();
          var userName = childData.userName;
          document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML += "<tr><td> " + userName + "</td></tr>";
        });
      }

    );
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question, which unfortunately doesn't give us a lot of context on the path to the data. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I have replaced the image with the json link. To put the text within here will be messy due to the database size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the relevant code:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('data/xbox/3787955/teams');
var ref = rootRef.child('1009254444');
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
    document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "";
    snap.forEach(function(child) {
      var childData = child.val();
      var userName = childData.userName;
      document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML += "<tr><td> " + userName + "</td></tr>";
    });
  }
);
```

This is reading the path `/data/xbox/3787955/teams/1009254444`, which leads to this [URL](https://cfm-stats.firebaseio.com/data/xbox/3787955/teams/1009254444.json?print=pretty) and this data:

```
{
  "abbrName" : "BKN",
  "awayLosses" : 1,
  "awayTies" : 0,
  "awayWins" : 6,
  "calendarYear" : 2021,
  "capAvailable" : 5940000,
  "capRoom" : 218000000,
  "capSpent" : 212060000,
  "cityName" : "Brooklyn",
  "confLosses" : 4,
  "confTies" : 0,
  "confWins" : 7,
  "conferenceId" : 996409344,
  "conferenceName" : "AFC",
  "defPassYds" : 3036,
  "defPassYdsRank" : 14,
  "defRushYds" : 1464,
  "defRushYdsRank" : 15,
  "defScheme" : 14,
  "defTotalYds" : 4500,
  "defTotalYdsRank" : 14,
  "displayName" : "Beats",
  "divLosses" : 3,
  "divName" : "AFC East",
  "divTies" : 0,
  "divWins" : 2,
  "divisionId" : 1007288320,
  "divisionName" : "AFC East",
  "homeLosses" : 5,
  "homeTies" : 0,
  "homeWins" : 3,
  "injuryCount" : 1,
  "logoId" : 141,
  "netPts" : -1,
  "nickName" : "Beats",
  "offPassYds" : 2296,
  "offPassYdsRank" : 30,
  "offRushYds" : 1297,
  "offRushYdsRank" : 24,
  "offScheme" : 2,
  "offTotalYds" : 3593,
  "offTotalYdsRank" : 32,
  "ovrRating" : 81,
  "playoffStatus" : 1,
  "prevRank" : 1,
  "primaryColor" : 6501524,
  "ptsAgainst" : 26,
  "ptsAgainstRank" : 21,
  "ptsFor" : 26,
  "ptsForRank" : 12,
  "rank" : 10,
  "seasonIndex" : 2,
  "secondaryColor" : 11579052,
  "seed" : 6,
  "stageIndex" : 1,
  "tODiff" : 7,
  "teamId" : 1009254444,
  "teamName" : "Beats",
  "teamOvr" : 81,
  "totalLosses" : 6,
  "totalTies" : 0,
  "totalWins" : 9,
  "userName" : "SnapDan",
  "weekIndex" : 15,
  "winLossStreak" : 255,
  "winPct" : 0.6
}
```

Now in the callback you do `snap.forEach`. But there is no repeated structure in the JSON that you're reading, so this `forEach` will actually loop over each property: `abbrName`, `awayLosses`, `awayTies`, etc.

You probably want to remove the loop:

```
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
    document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "";
    var childData = snap.val();
    var userName = childData.userName;
    document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML += "<tr><td> " + userName + "</td></tr>";
  }
);
```

Or alternatively, listen one level higher in the tree, so that you get all teams:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('data/xbox/3787955/teams');
rootRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "";
    snap.forEach(function(child) {
      var childData = child.val();
      var userName = childData.userName;
      document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML += "<tr><td> " + userName + "</td></tr>";
    });
  }
);
```